# Product Page Gallery "TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function"

Tags: magento2, gallery, fotorama

Please can anyone assist, it is driving me crazy. There are quite a few answers on here regarding this, however none have them have worked.

Here is my requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    "jquery.bootstrap": "js/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
    "lity": "js/node_modules/lity/dist/lity.min",
    "fotorama/fotorama": "fotorama/fotorama"
  },
  shim: {
    "jquery.bootstrap": {
        'deps': ['jquery']
    },
    "lity": {
        'deps': ['jquery']
    },
    'fotorama/fotorama': {
      'deps': ['jquery']
    }
  }
};
```

I am developing a custom theme.

This is the error I am facing in the console.

```
gallery.js:297 Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function
    at UiClass.initGallery (gallery.js:297)
    at UiClass.initialize (gallery.js:139)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
    at UiClass (class.js:49)
    at main.js:31
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
    at require.js:132
    at require.js:1156
```

Can anyone assist, please?

Comment: Hi, did you find solution ? i am having same issue. if you fixed it please add your solution. Thanks

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: any solution on this @Steven